# Pathfinder not working well in Illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I am having an issue with the pathfinder tool in Illustrator CC. Every time I use *minus front* this happens (see image below). As you can see, it does not detract exactly to the path/curve. Is there a setting I am missing? why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening is you have a stroke color that matches the fill color applied to your shape. You can do one of two things:

Option 1: Change the stroke color to NONE on your overlapping objects. (I prefer this option, because the shape remains an easily editable shape.)

Option 2: Make a duplicate of your objects, because what you will do next will make them more difficult to edit. Then, select your objects and apply Edit > Expand Appearance

In BOTH cases, you will then be able to apply Minus Front without the resulting shape "expanding" to match/include the stroke.

Comment: thanks dan but i will still need to edit manually  at the end.....i hope that adobe fixes this. I need to check at office, if its a cc issue or not coz my other fines are running on cs5 and cs6